# libre office 5.2 menu not integrated to ubuntu status bar on top

Tags: libreoffice, menu, statusbar

I have updated libre office through Ubuntu software centre to 5.2 on Xenial.

The menu of libre office is not integrated in the Ubuntu status bar on top.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above by uninstalling LibreOffice and reinstalling it fresh though the software centre instead of leaving the update installed.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer, since it was the solution to the problem! :) This helps others if they have the same issue.